# Python HDF5 / NumPy printing array differently

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5

I am new to numpy and hdf5 and am trying to follow 'HDF5 is for lovers' tutorial by Anthony Scopatz.

I'm passing a numpy array to hdf5 table but when I read the values from hdf5, it seems to be differently encoded: Here's the code:

```
dt = np.dtype([('id',int),('name','S10')])
knights = np.array([(42,'Lancelot'),(32,'Bedivere')])
f.createTable('/','knights',dt)
f.root.knights.append(knights)
f.root.knights[0]
```

Outputs:

```
(12852, '\x00\x00\x00Lancelot')
```

What's happening here? Why do I not get the original input i.e. '42', 'Lancelot' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I've figured it out.

I didn't specify the the dtype when creating a numpy array. The second line of the code should be:

```
knights = np.array([(42,'Lancelot'),(32,'Bedivere')], dt)
```